# What is the difference between a sample, a pixel and a fragment?

Tags: opengl, shader

I still can't wrap my head around what differences are there between a sample/pixel/fragment.

Since the fragment shader executes per pixel, I think a fragment just refers to a pixel, is this correct? Can anybody give me an example and definition of each one?

Comment: If you're looking for definitions, I assume you looked at the wiki? For example [this](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Fragment) and [this](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Per-Sample_Processing) page?

Comment: Yes, I did, though I still don't understand. For example, "Each fragment represents a sample-sized segment of a rasterized Primitive." What do they mean  by sample-sized?

Comment: it means that fragment can have different size than pixel for example if you are multi-sampling for anti-aliasing  purpose. Fragment is converted to pixel in the last stage of rendering. I see it like this: `Fragment` is atomic unit of your rendering target buffer(s) and `Pixel` is atomic unit of Rendering device (screen). Also fragment have more information then pixel like: Z coordinate, all colors and target buffer values,... That is at least how I see it.

Answer (score 14):

A fragment shader executes per fragment and emits pixels. They are very similar, but not the same.

> A Fragment is a collection of values produced by the Rasterizer. Each fragment represents a sample-sized segment of a rasterized Primitive. The size covered by a fragment is related to the pixel area, but rasterization can produce multiple fragments from the same triangle per-pixel, depending on various multisampling parameters and OpenGL state. There will be at least one fragment produced for every pixel area covered by the primitive being rasterized. [Source](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment)

So, if you disable multisampling / antialiasing completely, each fragment should map to one pixel. But if you enable it, multiple fragments will be interpolated to form a single pixel.

The differentiation can also be seen in the Rendering Pipelines of OpenGL here: https://openglinsights.com/pipeline.html

Comment: Is it not possible to have a fragment that covers more that one pixel? As in a Retro shader.

Answer (score 5):

A pixel is a screen element.
A fragment is the corresponding portion for a given geometric primitive +- covering the pixel.
For antialiasing (and more) several samples can be pickup in a pixel.

A pixel values is the mean of samples values, and the fragments from several triangles might contribute to a given pixel.